# Why domain is not released for registering yet?

Tags: domains, multiple-domains, domain-registrar

I am interested in domain which is in pendingDelete state since 19th of October (line form whois to confirm it `Updated Date: 2023-10-19T11`) so according to ICANN after 5 calendar days it should be released to public and its not. How long it may take? Is there any way to check exact date of drop?